# `yaxp` is no longer working like it used to

Tags: r, histogram

When I teach histograms using R, I use the `yaxp` parameter to adjust the y-axis. Here is an example of the code:

```
hist(bookspending$'Dollars on books', yaxp = c(0,9,9))
```

This produces a histogram where the y-axis has tick marks at 0, at 9, and a tick mark at every integer in between. Here is a picture of it:

[image: histogram, yaxp works]

I'm using Rstudio version 1.4.1717 and R version 4.1.1. This has worked the past 4 years. This semester the `yaxp` parameter isn't working for some students. I replicated the problem using the web-based version of R. Using the same code, the `yaxp` parameter makes no changes to the histogram. Here is the picture:

[image: histogram, yaxp does not work]

Why does `yaxp` no longer work for the online version, but it works for my version? How do you adjust the y-axis without `yaxp`?

Comment: See comments in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73720226/has-something-happened-to-the-yaxp-command-in-r

Comment: Honestly, this is arguably (and I’d argue this *strongly!*) a bug that was introduced in R 4.2.0. But since the documentation of the `hist` function is hopelessly vague it’s not really specified whether this was ever supported or just happened to work by chance.

Comment: @KonradRudolph the docs for `graphics:::plot.hist` say that `...` will be passed to `title` and `axis`, and they are, but from R 4.2.0 onwards the y axis breaks are decided for you because the `at` argument to the y axis is written for you, and `at` trumps `yaxp` inside `axis`

Comment: @AllanCameron Yes, I know …

Answer (score 1):

This happens because there was a change in the function `graphics:::plot.hist` in R version 4.2.0.

Previously, the part of the function that controlled the drawing of the axes was simply:

```r
  if (axes) {
     axis(1, ...)
     axis(2, ...)
   }
```

But it has been changed to

```r
  if (axes) {
     axis(1, ...)            
     yt <- axTicks(2)            
     if (freq && any(ni <- (yt%%1) != 0))                 
         yt <- yt[!ni]            
     axis(2, at = yt, ...)        
   }
```

Which means that the y axis breaks are now decided solely by the output of the function call `axTicks(2)`. Your `yaxp` argument is still passed to `axis`, but unfortunately, specifying `at` nullifies `yaxp`.

This is *sort of* mentioned in the [CRAN R News](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html), where it says:

> `hist.default()` gains new `fuzz` argument, and the histogram plot method no longer uses fractional axis ticks when displaying counts ("Frequency").

So the *reason* for the change was to prevent fractional axis ticks, but a side effect of this was preventing users from specifying y axis breaks. The only work-around for now it would seem, would be to add the axes manually as suggested in the last set of comments.

You may wish to file this as a bug report, since it seems to me that it should be possible to specify axis breaks *and* disallow fractional breaks without much difficulty.